# Making Python code with many "ifs" more efficient

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing methods for **"Telegram Bot"** class and one of the methods is **"getUpdate"** with 3 optional parameters - *"last_message","chat_id" and "text".*
If you pay attention to the code provided you'll be able to see that it consits of 5 ifs statement. I belive that there should be a way to reduce amount of it.

Json file looks next way:

{'ok': True, 'result': [{'update_id': xxxxx, 'message': {'message_id': 2, 'from': {'id': xxxxx, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Xxxx', 'last_name': 'Xxxx', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': xxxxxxx, 'first_name': 'Xxxx', 'last_name': 'Xxxx', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1560346414, 'text': 'Hi'}}, {'update_id': xxxxxx, 'message': {'message_id': 3, 'from': {'id': xxxxx, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'xxxx'}, 'chat': {'id': xxxx, 'first_name': 'Zzzz', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1560346988, 'text': '/start', 'entities': [{'offset': 0, 'length': 6, 'type': 'bot_command'}]}}, {'update_id': xzcdsfsdcd, 'message': {'message_id': 4, 'from': {'id': xxxx, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'xxxxx', 'language_code': 'ru'}, 'chat': {'id': xxxx, 'first_name': 'Zzzz', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1560346990, 'text': 'Hi'}}, {'update_id': xxxxxx, 'message': {'message_id': 22, 'from': {'id': yyyy, 'is_bot': False, 'first_name': 'Xxxx', 'last_name': 'Xxxx', 'language_code': 'en'}, 'chat': {'id': yyyy, 'first_name': 'Xxxx', 'last_name': 'Xxxx', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1560363527, 'text': 'Hey'}}]}

```
def getUpdates(self,last_message=False,chat_id=False,text=False):
    getUpdate_object=requests.get(self.base_url+"getUpdates").json()
    if last_message==True:
        last_message_object=getUpdate_object['result'][len(getUpdate_object['result'])-1]
        if chat_id==False and text==False:
            return last_message_object
        elif chat_id==True and text==False:
            return last_message_object['message']['chat']['id']
        elif chat_id==False and text==True:
            return last_message_object['message']['text']
        elif chat_id==True and text==True:
            chatid=last_message_object['message']['chat']['id']
            last_text=last_message_object['message']['text']
            return (chatid,last_text)
    else:
        return getUpdate_object
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to try every pair of `True` and `False` combination, you can just gradually build the result, based on each individual condition:

```py
def getUpdates(self,last_message=False,chat_id=False,text=False):
    getUpdate_object=requests.get(self.base_url+"getUpdates").json()
    if last_message==True:
        last_message_object=getUpdate_object['result'][len(getUpdate_object['result'])-1]
        if not chat_id and not text:
            return last_message_object
        result = []
        if chat_id:
            result.append(last_message_object['message']['chat']['id'])
        if text:
            result.append(last_message_object['message']['text'])
        return tuple(result)
    else:
        return getUpdate_object
```